# Inaccessible or not found

Tags: android, linux, bash, terminal, busybox

I have a problem with executing bash script on Android or TWRP. I use BusyBox 1.34.1 with Termux application.
The command that I use is **du**. All the time when I use variable with path in script I receive the error *Inaccessible or not found*.

**When I use static path I got the correct values:**

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mainLocation="/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test"

echo "Rozmiary katalogow:"
du -hd 1 /data/media/0/!Temp
```

Executing:

```
sh script3.sh    
: inaccessible or not found                     
: inaccessible or not found                     
Rozmiary katalogow:                             
697M    /data/media/0/!Temp
```

**But when I use the path from variable I got the error with no values:**

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mainLocation="/data/media/0/!Temp"

echo "Rozmiary katalogow:"
du -hd 1 "$mainLocation"
```

Executing:

```
sh script3.sh                  
: inaccessible or not found                     
: inaccessible or not found                     
Rozmiary katalogow:                             
: No such file or directory
```

So where is the problem?

Comment: First of all, `!` is a special character in bash, it will get used for history expansion. You need to use single quotes for your variable or rename the folder. Second, you can always use `bash -x` or `echo` to check the contents of a variable.

Comment: From the way those error messages are garbled, I'm pretty sure your script file has DOS/Windows line endings. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: @mashuptwice : But history expansion is only done if bash is  intaractive, so it should not matter here.

Comment: Maybe not relevant for this problem, but if you run your script as `sh script3.sh`, it is not executed by bash, but - as the command states - by `sh`. This will bite you once you are using bash-specific features. For debugging the problem, I would run it by `bash -x script3.sh` and analyze the diagnostic output you get. Also (for the safe side) you may do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` inside your script, so that we can see which bash is executing it.

Comment: Guys, thanks! Now it works awesome. The problem was with DOS line endings. I used `dos2unix` command :) Thanks for the `bash -x script3.sh` command - it is very helpful!